# Is it okay to use "to present" to mean "to make a gift" in informal setting?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

I'd like to say:

> I was going to present you another book.

Meaning, "to make a gift." But from what I can see, ["to present"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/present_3) and ["to gift"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/gift_2) are used in this sense in rather formal contexts. I could probably say "to give," but that doesn't sound like "making a gift." How do you say that?

Comment: In the sentence in the question, it would be more naturally phrased as the following: *I was going to present you **with** another book.* (Note that *give* does not take the preposition *with*, and *gift* works both ways.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right "to present" and "to gift" are rather formal

present is most commonly used in the format "I present to you the award for..."

In your sentence I would use give, give does mean a present, a gift

> I was going to give you another book

Here is a warning: I am waiting for the 'but' at the end of that because of the 'was'.

> I was going to give you another book, but Judy said your reading pile
>   is already a year long

Comment: On a side note, can you explain the "listening for" part? I probably understand what you mean, but I can't find it used that way. In the examples I can find it means "to wait for a [sound](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/listen+for)."

Comment: @x-yuri I have used a different word, is that better?

Comment: Not really. But the discussion sounds off-topic, so I decided to ask [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/227496/listen-for-to-mean-left-with-a-feeling). To make it clear, I'm not criticizing you, I'm trying to understand why it's okay to put it that way.